# How can i access a variable from one class and use it in another class?

Tags: python, pygame

### Heres my first class

```
 class snake:  
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
```

## Heres my second class

```
 class food:
    def __init__(self, food_x, food_y, food_width, food_height):
        self.x = food_x
        self.y = food_y
        self.width = food_width
        self.height = food_height
    def collition_detection(self):
        pass
```

I want to be able to access the position (x, y) form snake class to food class so that when i make a "collition_detection" function  in food class it wont throw an error at me saying "self.x" is not defined. Thanks.

Comment: You've to pass the instance of `snake` to `collition_detection`. (What you need is a parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a parameter in the method:

```
 class food:
    def __init__(self, food_x, food_y, food_width, food_height):
        self.x = food_x
        self.y = food_y
        self.width = food_width
        self.height = food_height

    def collition_detection(self, s):
        """ Return whether this food particle collides with the object `s`. """
        delta_x = math.abs(self.x - s.x)
        delta_y = math.abs(self.y - s.y)
        return (delta_x < (self.width + s.width) / 2) and (delta_y < (self.height + s.height) / 2)
```

A better approach might be to define a function that works for any two objects.  This way, you can extend the functionality to any classes with attributes `x`, `y`, `height`, `width`.

```
def is_collision(obj1, obj2):
    """ Return whether obj1 and obj2 collide. """
    delta_x = math.abs(obj1.x - obj2.x)
    delta_y = math.abs(obj1.y - obj2.y)
    return (delta_x < (obj1.width + obj2.width) / 2) and (delta_y < (obj1.height + obj2.height) / 2)
```

You could then call it as follows:

```
s = Snake(...)
f_particle = food(...)

is_collision(s, f_particle)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to instance the class. Then you can use its methods and functions, but not its variables. Create a function within class that returns what you need, instance that class from within the other (or main program) and get the values returned.

Here goes an example:

```
class A:
    def m(self, x, y):
        return x + y

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()

    def call_a(self):
        a = self.a.m(1, 2)
        return a

c = B()
result = c.call_a()
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix would be to make the position a class variable (shared between all instances of snake). You achieve this by simply declaring it as:

```
class snake:
    common_x = None
    common_y = None
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        common_x = x
        common_y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
```

These variables are shared between all instances of snake and can be accessed via `snake.common_x` or `snake1 = snake(args); snake1.common_x`

This answers your question of how to access these variables from another class. Having said so, I would suggest you **don't do it this way**, since you might run into problems later on. Firstly, this allows you to only have one snake in your game. This can be fixed by having a list of positions in your class, but I still don't consider this an elegant approach. I think it would be best to have another class, e.g. 'game' which keeps track of all your game objects. This class would have a list of snakes, food, enemies (?), whatever you want to add. You can then connect all your elements to a game instance and that's how they'll be able to communicate.

```
class game:
    def __init__(snakes=[], food=[]):
        self.snakes = snakes
        self.food = food

class snake:
    def __init__(x,y,game):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.game = game
        self.game.snakes.append(self)

class food:
    def __init__(self,...):
        ....

    def collide(self):
        for snake in self.game.snakes:
            if self.x == snake.x and self.y == snake.y:
                # do collision handling
```

This is just an example on how to approach this, I'm not sure, if having collision handling done by the food object is really the best approach, but I guess you  get the idea.